# Calling a .net method from odoo

Tags: .net, odoo, xml-rpc

I know that with XML-RPC we can call some odoo methods (like search, execute, ...) from .Net application.
But is there any way to do it other way around, means calling .Net application methods from odoo with XML-RPC?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could use XML-RPC but remember you have the full goodness of the python standard library plus pypi.python.org at your disposal.  It largely depends on what kind of external interface your .net app presents. Maybe SOAP or JSON?

Comment: Thanks very much for you answer. You are totally right about using python libraries. I found a way to do this by using [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html).